# MYSQL SubQuery vs Join - both not good for me

Tags: mysql

I'm Using MYSQL.
I have three tables.

1. `people` table which consists of two columns:

   - id - Primary key in the table
   - name - The persons name
2. `income` table which contains incomes of the people from the people table.
   each record in this table respresents an income for a person.
   A single person could have zero or many incomes in this table.
   The tables structure is:

   - person_id (foreign key to the 'people' table)
   - amount (DECIMAL type - amount of money)
   - number_of_hours_for_amount (INTEGER type - number of hours needed to earn this income)
3. `expenses` table which contains peoples expenses.
   each record in this table represents an expense a person had,
   and how much items he bought in that single expense.
   A single person could have zero or many expense records in this table.
   The tables structure is:

   - person_id (foreign key to the 'people' table)
   - amount (DECIMAL type amount of money)
   - number_of_items_bought (INTEGER type - number of items bought in this expense)

What I'm trying to do is create ONE single query that will give me a list of all the people
(one record per person) and in each row i will have

- the person's name,
- the sum of all his incomes,
- the total number of hours he worked,
- the sum of all his expenses,
- the total number of items he bought.

The first naive approach I tried worked very well logically but had very poor performance,
it looked something like this:

```
SELECT name, income_sum, work_hours_sum, expenses_sum, items_count
FROM (people
      LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT person_id, sum(amount) as income_sum, 
                   sum(number_of_hours_for_amount) as work_hours_sum
            FROM income
            GROUP BY person_id) as income_subquery
      ON people.id = income_subquery.person_id)

LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT person_id, sum(amount) as expenses_sum, 
             sum(number_of_items_bought) as items_count
      FROM expenses
      GROUP BY person_id) as income_subquery
ON people.id = income_subquery.person_id
```

The problem with this query as far as I understand is that once I get the data from the subqueries - the join is done very inefficiently
because there is no good use of the index's on these tables because they are temporary subquery tables.

The best way to make good use of the existing index's would be to have the join done between the three tables directly
and not via subqueries.
But this wouldn't be a correct solution because it would create a cartesian product which would add duplicate values to the aggregation summing
from records that would appear more then they should.

(Another option I tried was to have the income and expenses values for each person calculated as a select_expressions 
in the SELECT section (dependent subqueries). This also didn't work fast enough)

I'm looking for a query that would be efficient and give me these results.

Comment: How often do you update income and expenses? Can you keep their sums aggregated in another tables?

Comment: How many rows are in the tables?  How slow is "not fast"?

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN output and the design of the 3 tables (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs)?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have indexes that can efficiently help the queries.

Comment: I think table `income` should be `expenses` in the second LEFT JOIN in your example code above?  And you use the `income_subquery` alias twice too.  Looks like a copy & paste error, maybe only affecting your post here, not your original code.

Comment: Hey, yes the income should be expenses. fixed.

I cannot aggregate their sums into other tables, because sometimes this query also has a date factor so each time it could be a different query.

I have indexes. The problem is mysql doesn't the indexes because the join is between two temporary tables that are created from the subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

You're right you have an unavoidable Cartesian product here.  You can decompose this problem into two subqueries:

One for income:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, SUM(i.amount) AS income_sum, SUM(number_of_hours_for_amount) AS work_hours_sum
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN income i ON p.id = i.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;

+----+---------+------------+----------------+
| id | name    | income_sum | work_hours_sum |
+----+---------+------------+----------------+
|  1 | Groucho |      20.00 |             20 |
|  2 | Harpo   |      40.00 |             40 |
|  3 | Chico   |      60.00 |             60 |
+----+---------+------------+----------------+
```

Here's the EXPLAIN for that query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

One for expenses:

```
SELECT p.id, SUM(e.amount) AS expenses_sum, SUM(number_of_items_bought) AS items_count
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN expenses e ON p.id = e.person_id
GROUP BY p.id;

+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | expenses_sum | items_count |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |        30.00 |           4 |
|  2 |        30.00 |           4 |
|  3 |        30.00 |           4 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

We see in the above EXPLAIN reports that the queries use table-scans (type "ALL") on the income and expenses tables, and join without an index ("Using join buffer").  The red flag is that you have *two* tables involved in a join where both used access type "ALL".  If you have more than a trivial number of rows in these tables, it become very costly.  It often goes along with "Using join buffer" and that's another red flag for a costly query.

Finally, it does the GROUP BY inefficiently, using temporary table and filesort.  This is another performance killer.

[Block Nested Loop](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-optimization.html) is a MySQL 5.6 thing.  You won't see that if you use an earlier version of MySQL.

The following indexes should help make these queries much better:

```
ALTER TABLE income ADD KEY (person_id, amount, number_of_hours_for_amount);
ALTER TABLE expenses ADD KEY (person_id, amount, number_of_items_bought);
```

Now the EXPLAIN reports no longer show the inefficient accesses.  The join is done with an index (type "ref") and the temp table and filesort are gone.  "Using index" indicates that it's accessing the joined tables solely by the columns in the index, there's no need to touch the table row at all.

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | NULL      |    3 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ref   | person_id     | person_id | 5       | test.p.id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+

+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | NULL      |    3 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref   | person_id     | person_id | 5       | test.p.id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

You said you wanted to do this in one query, so here's how to do it:

We can join these individual two queries together *into one query* to get the result in a single row per person:

```
SELECT name, income_sum, work_hours_sum, expenses_sum, items_count
FROM
(SELECT p.id, p.name, SUM(i.amount) AS income_sum, SUM(number_of_hours_for_amount) AS work_hours_sum
 FROM people p
 LEFT OUTER JOIN income i ON p.id = i.person_id
 GROUP BY p.id) AS subq_i
INNER JOIN
(SELECT p.id, SUM(e.amount) AS expenses_sum, SUM(number_of_items_bought) AS items_count
 FROM people p
 LEFT OUTER JOIN expenses e ON p.id = e.person_id
 GROUP BY p.id) AS subq_e
USING (id);

+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+
| name    | income_sum | work_hours_sum | expenses_sum | items_count |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+
| Groucho |      20.00 |             20 |        30.00 |           4 |
| Harpo   |      40.00 |             40 |        30.00 |           4 |
| Chico   |      60.00 |             60 |        30.00 |           4 |
+---------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

The EXPLAIN doesn't look so bad even for this joined query.  No temp tables or filesorts or join buffers, and good use of covering indexes.

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL      |    3 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | subq_i.id |    2 | NULL        |
|  3 | DERIVED     | p          | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL      |    3 | Using index |
|  3 | DERIVED     | e          | ref   | person_id     | person_id   | 5       | test.p.id |    1 | Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | p          | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL      |    3 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | i          | ref   | person_id     | person_id   | 5       | test.p.id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-----------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: great! what happens if the last query uses LEFT instead of INNER among the two parts?, is this worst or better? thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to use LEFT join, since the set of rows per person will be identical.

Comment: I understand that both has identical set of `p.id`. (so inner and left act the same way here) The only reason I have to ask, is if `left` is more efficient in performance in this specific case, can you confirm that? thanks

Comment: An outer join will not perform better than an inner join, and may perform worse if it blocks the optimizer from using indexes (though probably not in this case).  This is not why you'd use an outer join anyway, you use it when it's the correct logical operation.

Comment: Still seeing `using join buffer`, what am I missing? You're using 5.6? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ec9/1

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks for the long answer - but I am looking for one query to solve the problem.

Comment: @OhadEilam, it *is* one query by the time I'm done.  Did you read to the end?

Comment: @BillKarwin, My bad. I'm sorry. The begining of your answer made me think you were going for a two-query solution. My problem with your final solution (the last query with the two sub-queries joined) is that at the end of the process mysql will join <derived2> and <dervied3> without any indexing or smart joining, and because in my case I have about 1-2K rows on each of these subqueries - it will take about 10 seconds which is too long for me.

Comment: Well, you've had multiple solutions proposed by a bunch of people.  I respectfully advise you to reconsider your requirement to do this in one query.

Comment: I have no choice... I'm working with a web-application-builder that allows only one query to define the contents of each web-page...

Comment: Then you have just collided with the [Law of Leaky Abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).  In other words, your web app builder can't handle the complexity of your current task for it, therefore you have to break out of the web app builder somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Both joins should make use of the index on `people.id`.

```
SELECT name, income_sum, work_hours_sum, expenses_sum, items_count
FROM people

LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT person_id, sum(amount) as income_sum, 
             sum(number_of_hours_for_amount) as work_hours_sum
      FROM income
      GROUP BY person_id) as income_subquery
ON people.id = income_subquery.person_id

LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT person_id, sum(amount) as expenses_sum, 
             sum(number_of_items_bought) as items_count
      FROM expenses
      GROUP BY person_id) as expenses_subquery
ON people.id = expenses_subquery.person_id
```

Ideally, a good query optimizer would realize that your original SQL is equivalent to this. But you're using MySQL, so I don't expect ideal optimization.

Make sure you have indexes on `income.person_id` and `expenses.person_id` so the grouping in the subqueries will be efficient.

Comment: . . How is this different from the query in the OP?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it doesn't do a join between two subqueries, it does two joins both with the main table.

Comment: @Barmar you are wrong, your queries are identical, if one removes the redundant parentheses.

Comment: Yupp, thanks for the idea - but same problem here. identical.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you pretty close:

```
select id, name, (select sum(amount) from income i where i.person_id = p.id) as 'total_income_amount',
                 (select sum(number_of_hours_for_amount) from income i where i.person_id = p.id) as 'total_number_of_hours_for_amount',
                 (select sum(amount) from expenses e where e.person_id = p.id) as 'total_expenses_amount',
                 (select sum(number_of_items_bought) from expenses e where e.person_id = p.id) as 'total_number_of_items_bought'
from   people p;
```

Comment: That's a nice idea I did try, but it was bad performance-wise.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can skip the JOIN altogether.

```
SELECT person_id
     , MIN(name) AS name
     , SUM(income_sum) AS income_sum
     , SUM(work_hours_sum) AS work_hours_sum
     , SUM(expenses_sum) AS expenses_sum
     , SUM(items_count) AS items_count
FROM (
SELECT id AS person_id
     , name
     , NULL AS income_sum
     , NULL AS work_hours_sum
     , NULL AS expenses_sum
     , NULL AS items_count
  FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id
     , NULL AS name
     , sum(amount) AS income_sum
     , sum(number_of_hours_for_amount) AS work_hours_sum
     , NULL AS expenses_sum
     , NULL AS items_count
  FROM income
 GROUP BY person_id
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id
     , NULL AS name
     , NULL AS income_sum
     , NULL AS work_hours_sum
     , sum(amount) AS expenses_sum
     , sum(number_of_items_bought) AS items_count
  FROM expenses
 GROUP BY person_id
) as d
WHERE person_id IS NOT NULL -- my sql generates this row
 GROUP BY person_id
```

Comment: Hey - I really like this solution. I'm going to try this - but I'm really afraid that the grouping by person_id is going to be expensive because mysql will have to group the thousands of results with no index to help him... Dont you think?

Comment: I assume that you are worried about the CLUSTERING and not the INDEX, specifically. You don't want MySQL to use the index at all because that will be a two step process, get index then get data. Generally, you want to use INDEX only if you are returning a few rows.

Comment: But this grouping would expensive for thousands of records, right?

Comment: You cannot avoid GROUP BY in any query, since you need to get total income and expenses. This avoids the JOIN of multiple transactions.